# How to get the FTL patch for Linux?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I bought the game from the official website. How can I get the patch? I did get a "Steam key" I think, but I don't use Steam. I'm running Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the "Humble store" link that was sent to you by email after you bought FTL. There you can download the latest patch.

If you lost access to that email address and the link to your humble page, you might be out of luck.